# Add items to any object of ICollection<T> using reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I'm trying to support mapping to/from any kind of collection that implements `ICollection<T>` via reflection, because `ICollection<T>` requires implementation of the Add method.

This works fine for most common collection types, but fails for edge cases like `LinkedList<T>` where the Add method is hidden and can only be called by casting the `LinkedList<T>` to `ICollection<T>`.

However it's not possible to convert to `ICollection<>` because it is not covariant.

The other option I was considering was searching for both implicit and explicit implementations of Add, but I don't see any information on how to do this when the interface is generic?

What would be the correct approach to take?

Updated to show code snippet where I'm reflecting from xml to object mapping.

```
    private object CollectionXmlNodeListToObject(
         XmlNodeList nodeList, System.Type collectionType)
    {
        // this is not possible because ICollection<> is not covariant
        object collection = Convert.ChangeType(
              CreateInstanceOfType(collectionType), ICollection<>);
        Type containedType = collectionType.GetTypeInfo().GenericTypeArguments[0];

        foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
        {
            object value = CreateInstanceOfType(containedType);

            if (containedType.IsClass && MetaDataCache.Contains(containedType))
                value = ToObject(value, node, node.Name);
            else
                value = node.InnerText;

            // this throws NullReferenceException when the type is LinkedList,
            // because this is explicitly implemented in LinkedList
            collectionType.GetMethod("Add")
                 .Invoke(collection, new[] { value });
        }

        return collection;
    }
```

I am writing a small framework to map from object to xml using class and property attributes. So I cannot use generics because all of this is being done at runtime.

I initially was checking for `IEnumerable` before, but ran into other oddities with it (strings implement `IEnumerable` and are immutable) that I decided it was safest to stick to `ICollection<>`

Comment: So are you saying you have a reflection solution that doesn't work in some situations, or you want one? Also can you please show us the code you have

Comment: I have a reflection solution that works for most situations except these edge cases. I have updated my question to include code demonstrating the issue.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but most list types offer a constructor that takes an `IEnumerable<T>`. Is there a reason why you would rather not use that?

Comment: Also what @John said

Comment: @John, types like string also implement IEnumerable and I don't want to have those accidentally be mapped as lists when they are really not. Also IEnumerable is immutable and so you have to assume that each type that implements IEnumerable will have a ctor that takes (IEnumerable<T>)

Comment: Side note: Be careful with strange things like `MyCol<TOne, TTwo> : ICollection<KeyValuePair<TOne, TTwo>>` if you care.

Comment: doesn't IDictionary<K,V> implement ICollection<KeyValuePair<K,V>? Not related to this question, but I am also handling IDictionary types as well.

Comment: Side note 2: Michael Randall solutions with generic method would have produced so much simple/safer code with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-call-a-generic-method (probably `dynamic` would even hide all reflection)… but they removed that perfectly fine answer for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With explicit interface implementation, the object has all the interface methods, but the object's Type does not.

So here's how to add an item to a `LinkedList<T>`, or any `ICollection<T>` through reflection:

```
        var ll = new LinkedList<int>();

        var t = typeof(int);

        var colType = typeof(ICollection<>).MakeGenericType(t);

        var addMethod = colType.GetMethod("Add");

        addMethod.Invoke(ll, new object[] { 1 });
```

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is met at compile-time using the [`Cast<T>()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.cast?view=netframework-4.7.2) method. You just need a run-time version, which is pretty straightforward:

```
static public object LateCast(this ICollection items, Type itemType)
{
    var methodDefintionForCast = typeof(System.Linq.Enumerable)
        .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
        .Where(mi => mi.Name == "Cast")
        .Select(mi => mi.GetGenericMethodDefinition())
        .Single(gmd => gmd != null && gmd.GetGenericArguments().Length == 1);

    var method = methodDefintionForCast.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { itemType });
    return method.Invoke(null, new[] { items });
}
```

Now you can take any non-generic collection and make it generic at run-time. For example, these two are equivalent:

```
var list = nodeList.Cast<XmlNode>();
object list = nodeList.LateCast(typeof(XmlNode));
```

And you can convert a whole collection with this:

```
static public IEnumerable ConvertToGeneric(this ICollection source, Type collectionType)
{
    return source.LateCast(collectionType.GetGenericArguments()[0]) as IEnumerable;
}

object list = nodeList.ConvertToGeneric(nodeList, typeof(ICollection<XmlNode>));
```

This solution works with linked lists as well as all the other collection types.

See my working example on [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4DI8i1)

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much all .NET collections take an `IEnumerable<T>` as the constructor, so you could make use of that:

```
private static object CollectionXmlNodeListToObject(System.Type collectionType)
{
    // T
    Type containedType = collectionType.GetTypeInfo().GenericTypeArguments[0];
    // List<T>
    Type interimListType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(containedType);
    // IEnumerable<T>
    Type ienumerableType = typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(containedType);

    IList interimList = Activator.CreateInstance(interimListType) as IList;

    interimList.Add(null);
    interimList.Add(null);
    interimList.Add(null);
    interimList.Add(null);

    // If we can directly assign the interim list, do so
    if (collectionType == interimListType || collectionType.IsAssignableFrom(interimListType))
    {
        return interimList;
    }

    // Try to get the IEnumerable<T> constructor and use that to construct the collection object
    var constructor = collectionType.GetConstructor(new Type[] { ienumerableType });
    if (constructor != null)
    {
        return constructor.Invoke(new object[] { interimList });
    }
    else
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/CJIF88785)

Obviously you could optimise this by moving the list population to another method, and then maybe use your existing method as far as you can, and then use this where you can't.